# How to pass an object to a ModelAttrbiute in MockMVC post?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, mockmvc

User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@NotBlank
@Column(name="username")
private String username;

@NotEmpty
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
                             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})
private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/users/edit/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "AddUserView";
    }

    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

Test with MockMVC:

```
@Test
public void performUpdateUserTest() throws Throwable {
            mockMvc.perform(post("/users/edit/{id}", user.getId())
                   .param("username", "User"));
}
```

Well, fine, I can pass a param *username* as always using **param()**. But what should I do with *ROLES*? This field is a separate object. I can't pass it using **param()**. Then how is it possible to pass it in the test?

The only way out I found is to create an entity and pass it using **.flashAttr()**:

```
    @Test
    public void performUpdateUserTest() throws Throwable {
          User user = new User("User", new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(new Role("USER"))));
          mockMvc.perform(post("/users/edit/{id}", user.getId())
                 .flashAttr("user", user));
    }
```

But then, what if I need to test that user can't be updated because of binding error in the *ROLES* field(ROLES can't be null, and suppose, it was set as null)? Thus, I'm not able to create user(and use it with .flashAttr) already with a binding error as the exception will be thrown. And I still have to pass it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a long time of searching, I found out that I should add a converter to the MockMVC. What converter is you can read [HERE](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions), for instance.
I had it already in my project but didn't realize that it didn't work with MockMVC.

So, you can add the converter to MockMVC like that:

```
    @Autowired
    private StringToRoleConverter stringToRoleConverter;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        FormattingConversionService cs = new FormattingConversionService();
        cs.addConverter(stringToRoleConverter);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController)
                .setConversionService(cs)
                .build();
    }
```

Converter itself:

```
@Component
public class StringToRoleConverter implements Converter<String, Role> {

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @Override
    public Role convert(String id) {
        Role role = roleService.findById(Integer.valueOf(id));

        return role;
    }

}
```

And then I can add param like that:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/users/edit/{id}", user.getId())
        .param("roles", "2"))
```

though I'm passing a string there, it will be converter to Role with the help of Spring converter.